# How to pass variables to IN clause of MySQL query in pandas.read_sql_query?

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am writing a generic function to query a database where I want to use *args to get values. Here's the function

```
def get_latest_value(col_name, *args):
    query = "select * from latest_value where {column} in (%s)"
    query = query.format(**dict(column=col_name))
    results = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine, params = [args])
    return(results)
```

However, when I run this, I get this error:

```
ProgrammingError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.ProgrammingError) not all arguments converted during bytes formatting
[SQL: select * from latest_value where amfi_code in (%s)]
[parameters: (100370, 100371)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

I even tried converting the *args to a list before passing it, but that didn't help either.

Not able to figure out how to pass the values in *args to the IN clause. Any help is appreciated.

Also, is using string concatenation for column name this ways safe from sql injection attacks?

*Update:*

I changed the code as follows:

```
def get_latest_value(col_name, *args):
    query = "select * from latest_value where {column} in (%s)"
    query = query.format(**dict(column=col_name))
    conditions = ", ".join(map(str, args))
    results = pd.read_sql_query(query, engine, params = [conditions])
    return(results)
```

I don't get an error now, but I only get the results for the first value in args.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out exactly what, but I figured that sqlalchemy has a problem dealing with this scenario. It can be solved by using psycopg2 instead.

I wrote the code as follows

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(user='', host='', password='', database='')

query = "select * from latest_value where {column} = any(%s)"
query = query.format(**dict(column=col_name))
results = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=(args,))
```

Note the change in the query. Instead of using `in (%s)`, I have used `=any(%s)` as seen in the psycopg2 documentation.

Also note that for the above to work, args needs to be a Python list, not a tuple.